# Problem with feedparser entry decoding

Tags: python, atom-feed

I have the following [atom doc](https://gist.github.com/1019783#file_zotero.xml), which I'm attempting to parse. However, when I do the following:

```
parsed = feedparser.parse(doc)
entries = [a[content][0]['value'].encode('utf-8') for a in parsed]
j = [json.loads(e) for e in entries]
```

I get a UnicodeDecodeError for the second entry:
`'utf-8', '\x9d\xa9\x9e\x00\xc8\x9d\xb2\xe9\xa6z\xb3b\x82\x1bl\x0e\xb7\x9a\x9a\x96\xabz{_j[\x1e', 0, 1, 'ordinal not in range(128)'`

I'm trying to figure out where this bug is occurring; with me, or with the feedparser.

Answer (score 0):

The feedparser team [answered](http://code.google.com/p/feedparser/issues/detail?id=284) your question. Please mention on SO if you post your issues elsewhere. It would have saved me time.

Comment: can you try it with a "name" value of eight characters or less? It seems to choke if it's 9 chars or longer.